# This kernel does not support a non-PAE CPU

Tags: apt

I received the error message: `The package system is broken` and I am not, to my knowledge, using third party repositories. Following some of the recent posts on similar topics, I looked at other posts with similar issues and tried: `sudo apt-get -f install`

Results:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.11.0-19-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-lts-saucy-doc-3.11.0 linux-lts-saucy-source-3.11.0
  linux-lts-saucy-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed
  linux-image-3.11.0-19-generic
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 28 not to upgrade.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/57.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 154 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Indicated Yes

Results:

```
(Reading database ... 171297 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-image-3.11.0-19-generic (from .../linux-image-3.11.0-19-generic_3.11.0-19.33~precise1_i386.deb) ...
This kernel does not support a non-PAE CPU.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.11.0-19-generic_3.11.0-19.33~precise1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.11.0-19-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-19-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.11.0-19-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-19-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.11.0-19-generic_3.11.0-19.33~precise1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have absolutely no idea what to do next.

Comment: post the output of `uname -r`

Comment: Hello Avinash, output  of uname -r was 3.11.0-15-generic

Comment: try `sudo apt-get clean` and then `sudo apt-get install -f` .Please let me know whether it works or not.

Comment: this did not work and there were a number of error codes such as This kernel does not support a non-PAE CPU and E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: post the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-image-3.11.0-19-generic`. Is that it displays nothing?

Comment: linux-image-3.11.0-19-generic: command not found

Comment: sorry, now see the edit.

Comment: It displays nothing

Comment: tr@tr-LIFEBOOK-S7010:~$ dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-image-3.11.0-19-generic
tr@tr-LIFEBOOK-S7010:~$

Comment: post the output of `apt-cache policy linux-image-3.11.0-19-generic` in pastebin.com.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/KYHK7Vss and thank you for your Help Avinash

Comment: try `sudo apt-get clean`,`sudo apt-get autoremove` and `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists`

Comment: autoremove results - http://pastebin.com/0Vq1t1VT

Comment: try `sudo apt-mark hold linux-image-generic-lts-saucy` and then `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Avinash - that worked perfectly, you are a genius. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorted this Open /proc/cpuinfo in a text editor, save to the same location, problem will be sorted if you are using a PAE cpu! Seems to be a bug with the way the install script is interacting with procfs...

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with my early Pentium-m CPU which does not report PAE in the flags portion of `/proc/cpuinfo`.

As with the initial install (in my case 16.04), you have to add the "forcepae" kernel option when booting.

The best way to do this is to add it to: `/etc/grub.d/10_linux`

search for this line:  `args="$4"`

change to:  `args="$4 forcepae"`

save then execute:  `update-grub`

After reboot, you will now have "pae" in the flags portion of `/proc/cpuinfo` and the update will work.  It will also be persistent for future updates.

This assumes you have a real PAE CPU like the early Pentium-m that doesn't report its PAE capability.  Pretty much any x86 CPU since 1995 supports PAE, so this is 99.99% likely your problem.

Comment: It would be easier and more reliable to add the kernel parameter to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` in `/etc/default/grub`. Pre-existing files in `/etc/grub.d` source the former file but may be overwritten during package upgrades themselves.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, the output of `sudo apt-get autoremove` is,

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run ‘apt-get -f install’ to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 linux-image-generic-lts-saucy : Depends: linux-image-3.11.0-19-generic but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

It clearly shows that the package `linux-image-generic-lts-saucy` is trying to download and install the dependency package `linux-image-3.11.0-19-generic` which inturn produces the error `This kernel does not support a non-PAE CPU` while installing this new kernel.

Holding the main package (`linux-image-generic-lts-saucy`) will solves your problem. So you have to run the below commands to hold `linux-image-generic-lts-saucy` package,

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-mark hold linux-image-generic-lts-saucy
```

Finally fix the dependencies,

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a non-PAE CPU, so you are most likely upgrading to a kernel that doesn't. The upgrade process is smart, so it wont install a kernel that won't allow you to boot the system, so it fails the installation.

The way to prevent this is upgrading your CPU to one that supports PAE (you should buy a new one) or holding the package as Avinash explained in his answer.