# Error building a VM

Tags: kernel, kvm-virtualization

My system:

```
#uname -a
Linux hostname 3.13.0-57-generic #95-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 19 09:28:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am trying build a VM ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/CreateGuests ) with this command:

```
#ubuntu-vm-builder kvm trusty --libvirt qemu:///system
```

But in the end it fails with this error:

```
Unpacking linux-image-virtual (3.13.0.58.65) ...
, stderr: grep: /proc/cpuinfo: No such file or directory
**This kernel does not support a non-PAE CPU.**
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-58-generic_3.13.0-58.97_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-58-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-58-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-58-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-58-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-58-generic_3.13.0-58.97_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Looks like I do have a PAE CPU...

```
 #grep -i PAE /proc/cpuinfo
 flags      : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36
```

I want to build and host KVM VMs on this server.  What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:  I am testing it with --addpkg linux-image-generic

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/446802/this-kernel-does-not-support-a-non-pae-cpu

Comment: ^ saw that, not helpful

Comment: I would look into `/proc/cpuinfo: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Surprised that bug isnt fixed yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add the argument:

```
   --addpkg linux-image-generic
```

Answer (score 2):

Find dapper.py in python-vm-builder

```
dpkg -L python-vm-builder | grep 'dapper.py$'
```

Open it and locate install_kernel function. Modify it as below:

```
def install_kernel(self, destdir):
    try:
        self.run_in_target('mount', '-t', 'proc', 'proc', '/proc')
        run_cmd('chroot', destdir, 'apt-get', '--force-yes', '-y', 'install', self.kernel_name(), env={ 'DEBIAN_FRONTEND' : 'noninteractive' })
    finally:
        self.run_in_target('umount', '/proc')
```

Please see also:

[vmbuilder completely fails on Quantal due to kernel pae detection failure](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vm-builder/+bug/1037607)